# How to resemble a click event in a way that opens a link in a new window in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following code resembles a click on all links in the page (of course, after the first one the page will change and all task won't be completed and I give it just as an example):

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((e)=>{
    e.click();
});
```

---

What if I want to open all links in the page **in new windows** (then the task will be completed).

I tried this in console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((e)=>{
    e.window.open();
});
```

And

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((e)=>{
    e.click(window.open());
});
```

And

```
document.body.addEventListener(function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A' && e.target.href) {
        e.target.target = '_blank';
    }
}, true);
```

None worked.

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Do you want to *open* them, or update them so that they'll open a new window when the *user* clicks them? The browser isn't going to let you open all of them at once.

Comment: I want to open them.

Comment: All of them? All at once? The browser won't let you, that's something nefarious websites do.

Comment: Yes, one link after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function (el, i) { 
  console.log(el.href, i); 
  window.open(el.href, 'link' + i); 
});
```

Correct syntax would be the one above however browser will not let you open multiple windows at once due to potential abuses. Imagine a page that opens 20 new tabs for you ... not nice right.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thumbed up. Why do we need 'link' + I if we loop window.open for  all `a` tags with `forEach()`?